# C - hex value 0x00 not being written to file

Tags: c, hex, hexdump

I am writing a program and I want to write some hex addresses to the file. The problem is that when I `hexdump -C temp` the file, I only see `bc ab` and the `\x00` were not written to the file for some reason I don't understand. Maybe they were recognized as EOF characters? Any help is really appreciated.

```
File *file;
char *buffer, *ptr;

ptr = buffer;
*(ptr++) = '\xbc';
*(ptr++) = '\xab';
*(ptr++) = '\x00';  // problem
*(ptr++) = '\x00';

file = fopen("temp", "w");
if (file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Opening file failed.\n");
  exit(1);
}

fprintf(file, "%s", buffer);
fclose(file);
```

Comment: use open mode `"wb"`

Comment: also consider using `fwrite` rather than `fprintf` if you don't want it to stop at the first `\x00`

Comment: The value zero (\x00) is a special value (NULL) that is typically used to indicate the end of a string.

Comment: @Marker `0x00` is not NULL

Comment: @M.M, oops sorry, how about null character, or string terminator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to write null characters with fprintf's %s. Null character is the string terminator. It won't be written that way. Use fwrite or fputc.